# auto generate CRUD view in angular 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, crud

Is there any framework could help to generate CRUD crud view files form table in DB using MVC project but the front-end is angular?

Sorry. I had googling for some hours . But still cant find the solution.
All I found is manual creating the controllers/Models/Views(Angular files (services-components-models)
Nothing ease these steps and generate the view.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I never tried out [ng-momentum](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-momentum) but you should give it a try as there is a crud part (but you need to create the project with it).

Answer (score -1):

It is always not the best practice to generate CRUD views from a relational schema, unless you just want to build a toy app for demo purpose.

However, there is a way to simplify the building of CRUD apps. Please check the project: [Json-on-relations](https://github.com/VinceZK/json-on-relations)